# How to install rclone in Ubuntu without root?

Tags: rclone

I read from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638885/onedrive-on-linux-without-root that I can install rclone without root by following https://rclone.org/install/#linux-installation-from-precompiled-binary

I ran the 1st 3 lines

```
curl -O https://downloads.rclone.org/rclone-current-linux-amd64.zip
unzip rclone-current-linux-amd64.zip
cd rclone-*-linux-amd64
```

but the rest still require sudo. How should I proceed?

Copy binary file

```
sudo cp rclone /usr/bin/
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/rclone
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/rclone
```

Install manpage

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/man/man1
sudo cp rclone.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/
sudo mandb
```

Run rclone config to setup. See rclone config docs for more details.

```
rclone config
```

Comment: Debian/Ubuntu don't use root account by default. Instead elevated privileges are requested with sudo. There's a comment under the question you linked asking for clatification and this suggests that OP is confused.

Comment: @ChanganAuto so what should I do? What is the solution? What must I type?

Comment: Like in the linked question, I think you're confusing use with installation. Many or most programs run with the regular user(s) but that doesn't mean they can be installed without privileges. If you don't have sudo privileges on the machine you can't install software.

Comment: isn't `rclone` simply installable from the ubuntu software center or have I missed the point of your question?

Answer (score 5):

Leave out the `sudo` and change `/usr/bin` to `~/.local/bin`, and `/usr/local/share/man` by `~/.local/share/man`. Create these folders first if you do not already have them.

This installs `rclone` in your own home folder, not requiring you to be root.

Thus, the commands to install the binary and man page become:

```
cp rclone ~/.local/bin
chmod +x ~/.local/bin/rclone
cp rclone.1 ~/.local/share/man/man1/
```

Note that the command, installed this way, will be available only to you, not to other users on the system. To install software for any user of the system, you need to be root, i.e., administrator. There is no way around this.

Comment: "change /usr/bin to ~/local/bin, and /usr/local/share/man by .local/share/man" : Can you please let me know where are we supposed to make these changes?

Comment: `sudo cp rclone /usr/bin/` -> `cp rclone ~/.local/bin`

Comment: @user408108 I added the adapted commands. Log out then back in for this to work if you did not yet have the extra folders. Let me know if `man rclone`works without any further intervention (i.e., I think there may be no need to run `mandb`

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the adapted commands. I have successfully installed rclone on remote server without root permissions. I have also setup sync with OneDrive Business and it is working as expected. 
The command 'man rclone' is not working.  The message "No manual entry for rclone" is shown.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Some `mandb` command will be needed to tell man where to find the manual.

Comment: If not already in PATH remember to add `~/.local/bin` to path.

Comment: @ru111 on Ubuntu, this is automatically done on your next login